# determine the width of input field

Tags: sapui5

I have a dialog that contains following form:
[image]

How can I set the input usual day wider then Ver. input? The ratio should be 3:1.

the code snippet for the simple form:

```
<f:SimpleForm id="form-add-item"
                    maxContainerCols="2"
                    editable="true"
                    class="editableForm">
        <f:content>
          <l:VerticalLayout>
            <Input value="{vmNewItem>/sPlant}" placeholder="{i18n>insColPlant}"/>
            <Input value="{vmNewItem>/sWorkCenter}" placeholder="{i18n>insColWorkCenter}"/>
            <l:HorizontalLayout>
              <Input value="{vmNewItem>/sUsualDay}" placeholder="{i18n>insColUsualDay}">
                <layoutData>
                  <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S4" linebreak="true"/>
                </layoutData>
              </Input>
              <Input value="{vmNewItem>/sUsualDayVer}" placeholder="{i18n>insColUsualDayVer}">
              </Input>
            </l:HorizontalLayout>
            <l:HorizontalLayout>
              <Input value="{vmNewItem>/sSpecialDay}" placeholder="{i18n>insColSpecialDay}"/>
              <Input value="{vmNewItem>/sSpecialDayVer}" placeholder="{i18n>insColSpecialDayVer}"/>
            </l:HorizontalLayout>
          </l:VerticalLayout>

        </f:content>
      </f:SimpleForm>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several ways this could be achieved. if you are using the SimpleForm control, one possible way is to use a ResponsiveGridLayout and specify layoutData as follows...

```
    <f:SimpleForm id="form-add-item"
                maxContainerCols="2"
                editable="true"
                class="editableForm"
                layout="ResponsiveGridLayout">
        <f:content>
            <Input value="{vmNewItem>/sPlant}" placeholder="{i18n>insColPlant}">
                <layoutData>
                  <l:GridData span="L12 M12 S12" />
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
            <Input value="{vmNewItem>/sWorkCenter}" placeholder="{i18n>insColWorkCenter}">
                <layoutData>
                  <l:GridData span="L12 M12 S12" />
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
            <Input value="{vmNewItem>/sUsualDay}" placeholder="{i18n>insColUsualDay}">
                <layoutData>
                  <l:GridData span="L9 M9 S9"  />
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
            <Input value="{vmNewItem>/sUsualDayVer}" placeholder="{i18n>insColUsualDayVer}">
                <layoutData>
                  <l:GridData span="L3 M3 S3" />
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
            <Input value="{vmNewItem>/sSpecialDay}" placeholder="{i18n>insColSpecialDay}">
                <layoutData>
                  <l:GridData span="L9 M9 S9"  />
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
            <Input value="{vmNewItem>/sSpecialDayVer}" placeholder="{i18n>insColSpecialDayVer}">
                <layoutData>
                  <l:GridData span="L3 M3 S3" />
                </layoutData>
            </Input>
        </f:content>
    </f:SimpleForm>
```